# Aurelia, check when DOM is compiled?

Tags: aurelia

How to check when DOM is compiled and inserted from Aurelia repeat cycle when the model is updated?

I have the following html:

```
<div clas="parent">
   <div class="list-group"> 
      <a repeat.for="$item of treeData">${$item.label}</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here I need to know when all `<a>` tags are listed in the DOM, in order to run jquery scroll plugin on the parent `<div>` container.

At first load, I do that from the attached() method and all is fine.

When I update the **treeData** model from a listener, and try to update the jquery scroll plugin, it looks that the DOM is not compiled, so my scroll plugin can not update properly.

If I put timeout with some minimum value like 200ms it works, but I don't think it is a reliable workaround.

So is there a way to solve that?

Thanks!

My View Model:

```
@customElement('tree-view')
@inject(Element, ViewResources, BindingEngine)
export class TreeView {
  @bindable data = [];
  @bindable filterFunc = null;
  @bindable filter = false;
  @bindable selectedItem;

  constructor(element, viewResources, bindingEngine) {
    this.element = element;
    this.viewResources = viewResources;
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
    this.dataPropertySubscription = this.bindingEngine
      .propertyObserver(this, 'data')
      .subscribe((newItems, oldItems) => {
        this.dataCollectionSubscription.dispose();
        this._subscribeToDataCollectionChanges();
        this.refresh();
      });

    this.refresh();

    if (this.filter === true) {
      this.filterChanged(this.filter);
    }

    if (this.selectedItem) {
      this.selectedItemChanged(this.selectedItem);
    }
  }

  attached() {
     $(this.element).perfectScrollbar();
  }


  refresh() {
    this.treeData = processData(this.data, this.filterFunc);
    this.listItemMap = new WeakMap();
    this.treeData.forEach(li => this.listItemMap.set(li.item, li));
    this.filterChanged(this.filter);

    $(this.element).perfectScrollbar('update');
  }
```

This is only part of the code, but most valuable I think. 
I attach the jq plugin in attached function and try to update it in refresh function. In general I have listener that track model in other view, which then update that one without triggering bind method.

Comment: show your view-model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to use something called `window.requestAnimationFrame` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).
In your view-model, when you modify your `treeData` array, try calling

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
  $.fn.somePlugin();
});
```

Haven't tested this out, but based off what you're telling me, this might do what you need.

Comment: Awesome, that do the job! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could push your code onto the microTaskQueue, which will schedule your function to be executed on the next event loop. For instance:

```
import { TaskQueue } from 'aurelia-task-queue';
//...
@inject(Element, ViewResources, BindingEngine, TaskQueue)
export class TreeView {

  constructor(element, viewResources, bindingEngine, taskQueue) {
    this.element = element;
    this.viewResources = viewResources;
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  refresh() {
    this.treeData = processData(this.data, this.filterFunc);
    this.listItemMap = new WeakMap();
    this.treeData.forEach(li => this.listItemMap.set(li.item, li));
    this.filterChanged(this.filter);

    // queue another task, which will execute after the tasks queued above ^^^
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
       $(this.element).perfectScrollbar('update');
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I try that as well, but it did not work! What do the job is window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: In theory, this should work @kaloyan-stamatov (for future reference). There might have been a technical bump along the way of implementation. window.requestAnimationFrame will wait until the next time the browser is told to "repaint" the screen. This will most likely be the same event as the next task in a micro task queue, so that's why in theory, this should work. However it takes a bit more setup to get the micro task queue to work. If you were doing any other kind of data operation (and not just a jQuery plugin for ui), the micro task queue would be the appropriate solution I believe.

Comment: Yep, but there are a lot of data operations in my project, some comes by events, which is not triggering Aurelia datacycle I guess. It is how I explain this malfunctioning of  queueMicroTask. Anyway Thanks!